# Is it possible to use __LINE__ in the auto-generated variable name in C?

Tags: c, macros

To avoid duplication, I want to use `__LINE__` in the auto-generated variable name.

```
#define ROUTE(path, impl) \
char * k##impl##__LINE__##_route = "{"#path":\""#impl"\"}";
```

But it always be treated as a normal string `__LINE__`.

Even if I define it as the following, I can not get what I want:

```
#define ROUTE(path, impl) ROUTE_(path, impl, __LINE__)

#define ROUTE_(path, impl, line) \
char * k##impl##line##_route = "{"#path":\""#impl"\"}";
```

Comment: ...and what happens to the part of code that uses that variable if you add a line before the variable declaration ....

Comment: What happens if you use the macro in two different source file, and it just happens to be at the same line in both? You can't have two different variables with the same name in multiple translation units.

Comment: @LPs Actually, I will not use the variable directly, it will generated data in the compiled target, I will read the data directly from the target. I name the variable just to meet the requirement of the compiler.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's a good question. I suppose usually it won't happen. Any suggestion? Actually I don't care the name, but the compiler doesn't allow duplication.

Comment: @someprogrammerdude:   You can have two different variables with the same name if they're both `static` (eg, local to the translation unit), right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need one more level of nesting:

```
#define ROUTE(path, impl) ROUTE_(path, impl, __LINE__)

#define ROUTE_(path, impl, line) ROUTE_1(path, impl, line)

#define ROUTE_1(path, impl, line) \
    char * k##impl##line##_route = "{"#path":\""#impl"\"}";
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
#define CAT_(A,B) A##B
#define CAT(A,B) CAT_(A,B)


#define ROUTE(path, impl) \
    char * CAT(CAT(k##impl,__LINE__),_route) = "{"#path":\""#impl"\"}";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using the variable try ["compound literals"](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    // using preprocessor 'trick'
    struct tm uniquenamewith__LINE__inthename = {0};
    uniquenamewith__LINE__inthename.tm_year = 2019 - 1900;
    uniquenamewith__LINE__inthename.tm_mon = 12 - 1;
    uniquenamewith__LINE__inthename.tm_mday = 18;
    time_t foo = mktime(&uniquenamewith__LINE__inthename);

    // using compound literal
    time_t bar = mktime(&(struct tm){.tm_year=2019-1900, .tm_mon=12-1, .tm_mday=18});

    printf("foo is %lu, bar is %lu\n", (unsigned long)foo, (unsigned long)bar);
    return 0;
}
```

See [code running on ideone](https://ideone.com/zJxxNz)